# Import RESTClient lib to jenkins-workflow groovy script

Tags: jenkins-workflow

I am trying to integrate Jenkins-workflow with artifactory.
Since https://github.com/jenkinsci/artifactory-plugin does not support jenkins-workflow so far, I came to the point I should either use shell scripts like https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples with sh command or my own groovy script.

I want to share this artifactory publisher librairy within the cps-global-lib. 
Thus, I can not store JFrogDev shell script within the global-lib as I won't be able to call it from my project flow.groovy file.
The only solution I found so far is to script a global utility function that imports

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
```

Unfortunately, the Snippet generator repots :

```
unable to resolve class groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
@ line 1, column 1.
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient;
^
1 error
```

How could I deal with this jenkins-workflow/artifactory integration ? Is there a way to enable RESTClient in jenkins-workflow global library ?

**[EDIT]**

Based on Jesse answer, I ended up writing a shell script in the workspace using `writeFile` workflow command. The shell script put local file to artifactory using `curl`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to refer to the RESTClient classes directly from the flow. Instead, run a `groovy` executable from a `sh` step. (You can define multiline string using a variety of syntaxes in Groovy, such as `'''`.)

Comment: And how do you do this on the Windows platform, where curl is not available?

Comment: You can install cURL for Windows, or use other native tools like Powershell.

Comment: [JENKINS-32263](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32263) would also offer a platform-independent step usable from Pipeline (formerly Workflow) for performing routine HTTP operations.